# Error returned when I executed an sql query, can anyone help me resolve this problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

Error returned is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near
> ''id_partenaire','logo_partenaire','logo_tnb','favicon','global_primary_color','g'
> at line 1

This is my query:

```
INSERT 
INTO
    CONFIGURATIONS_PARTENAIRES
    ('id_partenaire','logo_partenaire','logo_tnb','favicon','global_primary_color','global_secondary_color','global_infos_color','global_font_color','font_color_dark','font_color_light','moteur_ht','moteur_og','moteur_ht_primary_color','moteur_ht_secondary_color','moteur_og_primary_color','moteur_og_secondary_color') 
VALUES
    (16,'logo-2020-350x73-1.png','logo_tb.png','icon.gif','#ebebeb','#ffffff','#f50e98','#000000','#ffffff','#f06f05','1','1','#000000','#f06f05','#000000','#f06f05');
```

Comment: Properly formatted SQL is so much easier to read, and to write.

Comment: Why did you put quotes around the column names?

Comment: Yes, MySQL wants back-ticks for identifiers. (ANSI/ISO SQL has double quotes.)

Comment: those shown in the question are not back-ticks: they are single quotes! back-tick key is on the top left of a regular US keyboard underneath the ESC button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With back ticks instead of the quotes on the column names it should run better

```
INSERT INTO 
CONFIGURATIONS_PARTENAIRES
(`id_partenaire`,
`logo_partenaire`,
`logo_tnb`,
`favicon`,
`global_primary_color`,
`global_secondary_color`,
`global_infos_color`,
`global_font_color`,
`font_color_dark`,
`font_color_light`,
`moteur_ht`,
`moteur_og`,
`moteur_ht_primary_color`,
`moteur_ht_secondary_color`,
`moteur_og_primary_color`,
`moteur_og_secondary_color`) 
VALUES 
( 16
,'logo2020-350x73-1.png'
,'logo_tb.png'
,'icon.gif'
,'#ebebeb'
,'#ffffff'
,'#f50e98'
,'#000000'
,'#ffffff'
,'#f06f05'
,'1'
,'1'
,'#000000'
,'#f06f05'
,'#000000'
,'#f06f05');
```